# How to remove blur off toon shading blender render

Tags: rendering

[image: pacman3d]

This is my render. But how do I remove blur off the toon shader with the blender render? ¯_(ツ)_/¯

and I want it to look like this
[image]

Comment: this looks pretty sharp to me. what exactly is the problem with your image?

Comment: but i want it to look like the bottom image

Comment: I do not see any blur, just a difference in lighting.

Comment: The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing isn't a blur, it is reflections and highlights.

You can either turn the size and smooth down to zero for the diffuse and specular settings -

[image: diffuse secular settings]

or enable shadeless to eliminate all highlighting.

[image: shadeless option]

Comment: thx but i want the shading to be more 2D

Comment: @artmediafan2002XavierFreeman You can use small size values to reduce the amount of specular highlights. The shadeless option is as close to 2D as you will get and will be very similar to your second image.

Comment: what about freestyle

Comment: @artmediafan2002XavierFreeman freestyle can add outlines, it doesn't change the shading of the object surface.

Comment: what about ramp

Comment: i figured it out now 

Comment: As in the question, there are still some sort of Toon shadows; Which can't be achieved by checking Shadeless.

Comment: @ShehrozKhan shadeless will remove all of the specular highlights and shadows on the model, by adjusting the size and smooth you can adjust the size of the highlights.

Comment: I do not need anymore help but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now I figured out how to make my render look 2D.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that the models are Pac-Man, Blinky, Inky, Pinky, and Clyde.